# One server and Multi client chat box in UDP

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, client-server

I'm trying to design a chat application using UDP networking in java.

Here is my server:

```
package ChatBox;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; 
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server implements Runnable {

public Hashtable<String, InetAddress> table;
public Hashtable<String, Integer> tab;
DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(5050);
DatagramPacket pack;
private String str[];
int Port;

Server(String str[]) throws SocketException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    this.str = str;
    String Sname = str[2];
    System.out.println(Sname);
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    sock.receive(pack);
    String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    String s1 = s.replaceAll("\n", " ");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1, " ");
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 0, f3 = 0;
    String sender;

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String s2 = st.nextToken();
        if (s2.equals("Via:")) {
            if (st.nextToken().equals(Sname)) {
                f1 = 1;
            }
        } else if (s2.equals("To:")) {
            if (st.nextToken().equals(Sname)) {
                f2 = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(s2.equals("From:"))
        {
            sender = st.nextToken();
            table.put(sender, pack.getAddress());
        }
        else if (s2.equals("Port:")) {
            Port = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            if (tab.get(Port) != null) {
                f3 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if ((f1 == 1) && (f2 == 1) && (f3 == 1)) {
        new Thread(this).start();
    } else {
        if (f1 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Warning: Server name mismatch. Message dropped.");
        }
        if (f2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Warning: Server name mismatch. Message dropped.");
        }
        if (f3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Warning: Unknown recipient. Message dropped.");
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            String s;
            String namefind;
            String name = null;
            byte[] data = new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket receivePack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            sock.receive(receivePack);
            System.out.println(new String(receivePack.getData()));
            s = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            String s1 = s.replaceAll("\n", " ");
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1, " ");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                namefind=st.nextToken();
                if (namefind.equals("Body:")) {
                    namefind = st.nextToken();
                    StringTokenizer namefind2 = new StringTokenizer(namefind, "$");
                    name = namefind2.nextToken();
                    tab.put(name, Port);
                }
            }
            sendPackToClient(receivePack,name);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
public void sendPackToClient(DatagramPacket receivePack,String name) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = receivePack.getData();
    String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    InetAddress add = table.get(name);
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), s.getBytes("UTF-8").length, add, Port);
    sock.send(dp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
    try {
        String str[]={"java", "Server ","NetworkingAssignmentServer"};
        new Server(str);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my Client:

```
package ChatBox;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Client {

Thread send;
Thread accept;
DatagramPacket pack;
DatagramSocket sock;
private String str[];
String name, sname;
int listeningPort;
InetAddress server_ip;
String message, sender;

public Client(String s[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    this.str = s;
    name = str[2];
    System.out.println(name);
    listeningPort = Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
    server_ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    sname = str[5];
    System.out.println(sname);
    sock = new DatagramSocket(5050);
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    sock.receive(pack);
    String incoming = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    String s1 = incoming.replaceAll("\n", " ");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1, " ");
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 0;

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String s2 = st.nextToken();
        if (s2.equals("Via:")) {
            if (st.nextToken().equals(sname)) {
                f1 = 1;
            }
        } else if (s2.equals("To:")) {
            if (st.nextToken().equals(name)) {
                f2 = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    if ((f1 == 1) && (f2 == 1)) {
        send = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                        try {
                            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String in = input.nextLine();
                            System.out.println(in);
                            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
                            str.append("Via: ");
                            str.append(sname + "\n");
                            str.append("To: " + sname + "\n");
                            str.append("From: " + name + "\n");
                            str.append("Body: " + in);
                            byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                            data = str.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                            DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, host, 5050);
                            sock.send(sendPack);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        send.start();
        accept = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        sock = new DatagramSocket(5050);
                        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                        pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                        sock.receive(pack);
                        String incoming = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                        String s1 = incoming.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1, " ");
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            String s2 = st.nextToken();
                            if (s2.equals("From:")) {
                                s2 = st.nextToken();
                                StringTokenizer namefind = new StringTokenizer(s2, "$");
                                sender = namefind.nextToken();
                            } else if (s2.equals("Body:")) {
                                s2 = st.nextToken();
                                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                    message = st.nextToken();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(sender + " says: " + message);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (SocketException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        accept.start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str[] = {"Java", "Client", "Sheba", "12345", " 127.0.0.1", "NetworkingAssignmentServer"};
    new Client(str);
}

}
```

But i'm always getting errors, like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:392)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:242)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:299)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:271)
at ChatBox.Client.<init>(Client.java:44)
at ChatBox.Client.main(Client.java:140)
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:          Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What should i do? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should at least try to isolate the part of the code that raises the exception. Is this a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think you server and client use the same port and address, are you using the server and client at the same PC?

Comment: @user2760751 yes..Can you please tell me where i should make change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice server code and client code both use the same port 5050, when they are in the same PC, bind will return error.

So you should put different port to the server and client. Or you can use different PC to run the server and client separately.

Put different in this statement:

```
sock = new DatagramSocket(5050); // Server : 5050, Client 5000
```